# How to KeyDown event when you have buttons in your form

Tags: c#, winforms, keydown

I made a program in WinForms that shows a blank screen, and then if you press Enter then something happens..
well i used this code:

```
 private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            label1.Visible = false;
            Colors.Start();

        }
```

Now when I tried to add some buttons to the blank screen, the option to click on Enter just don't work anymore... no matter what I do. and please don't earse this question, I'm kind of new in programming and I know there's alot of questions like that one, but I couldn't understand them...
thanks

Comment: What is the definition of Colors.Start?

Comment: What exactly isn't working here? Do you have a separate KeyDown event for your buttons? I've tried to repro this and the KeyDown event still fires.

Comment: the new button that you added might have got the focus.. try to select the form and then press enter.. see if it works

Comment: @Neolisk This is a Timer

Comment: @UzairAhmedSiddiqui How to select it?

Comment: `the option to click on Enter just don't work anymore` Please describe **how exactly** it does not work.

Comment: click on the title bar of the window

Comment: Most certainly one of your new controls now has focus and is receiving the KeyDown event. If you want all your controls to handle the same KeyDown event, then just map the event to the method you have already created.

Comment: @Neolisk I mean that nothing happens if you press enter..

Comment: @UzairAhmedSiddiqui I tried, it still not working

Comment: Can you add a screenshot explaining how it works now, and another one showing how you intend it to work? I'm still having a hard time making sense of your question.

Comment: @Neolisk Whats not to uderstand? I want to press Enter and that it will work, even if I have a button in my form. because it's not working.

Comment: Override the ProcessCmdKey() method instead.

Comment: @RufusL Can you show me how to map the event to the method?

Comment: @DanielSagi Well, through the UI, you can select the control you want to map the KeyDown event, go to the properties window, click the 'Events` button (lightning bolt), click on `KeyDown`, then in the drop-down list choose your `Form1_KeyDown` method.

Comment: Umm, of course if the control is a Button, clicking Enter will trigger the Click() event, not the KeyDown event. Probably you should take the code that you want to execute in these events and put it in a separate function, then call that function from the events you want to trigger it.

Comment: and if you're dynamically adding the controls, then just do: controlName.KeyDown += Form1_KeyDown;

Answer (score 0):

Is the form's  `AcceptButton` property assigned to a button?

If so, that could be grabbing the Enter keystroke first.

Answer (score 0):

An example of the suggestion by Hans Passant:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if (keyData == Keys.Enter)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter");
            return true; // optionally prevent further action(s) on Enter; such as Button clicks
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
}
```

Note that if you return true, then controls like the buttons will not get the Enter keystroke.